# Left Outer Join Problem in Linq-To-Sql

Tags: c#, sql, database, linq-to-sql

Hi I have 5 tables. The necessary relationships are as follows

**Period**
Id
StartDate 
EndDate
IsDeleted

**Code**
Id
Name

**YearlyTarget**
Id
CodeId
PeriodId
YTAmount
IsDeleted

**AlteredTarget**
Id 
YearlyTargetId
AltAmount
IsDeleted

**Actual**
Id
AlteredTargetId
ActualAmount
IsDeleted

I have 4 quarters in year data. YearlyTarget exists for all quarters, AlteredTarget for Q1 and Actual for none.

My query is as follows:

```
from cl in this.Context.Codes    
join ytl in this.Context.YearlyTargets on cl.Id equals ytl.CodeId    
join pl in this.Context.Periods on ytl.PeriodId equals pl.Id    
join atl in this.Context.AlteredTargets on ytl.Id equals cdpl.YearlyTargetId into ccl    
join al in this.Context.Actuals on ytl.Id  equals al.AlteredTargets.YearlyTargetId into cal   
from cc in ccl.DefaultIfEmpty()    
from ca in cal.DefaultIfEmpty()
where cc.IsDeleted == false && ca.IsDeleted == false   
select new    
{    
    Year = pl.EndDate.Year,    
    PeriodType = (PeriodType)pl.PeriodType,    
    PeriodName = pl.StartDate,    
    CodeName = cl.CodeName,    
    YT = ytl.TargetAmount,    
    CDP = cc.AltAmount,    
    Actual = ca.ActualAmount    
};
```

the query returns empty. Can someone please tell me what's wrong with the query. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that it's the `where` clause which is messing you up. Don't forget that `cc` and `ca` can be null. Try changing the `where` clause to:

```
where (cc == null || !cc.IsDeleted) && (ca == null || !ca.IsDeleted)
```

You may also then need to change the projections where you use `cc` and `ca` to:

```
CDP = cc == null ? 0 : cc.AltAmount,    
Actual = ca == null ? 0 : ca.ActualAmount
```

I potentially nicer alternative to the existing `where` clause is to put the check for `IsDeleted` into the join:

```
join al in this.Context.Actuals.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted) 
  on ytl.Id  equals al.AlteredTargets.YearlyTargetId into cal
```

and the same for the other one. Note that this changes the meaning of the query if Actual values *do* exist but they're all deleted. I suspect it changes it to what you want the behaviour to be though...

Comment: thanks a lot, adding the verification in the join clause solved my problem.